# UserList overloading python 3.x

Tags: python, overloading

I'm trying to overload UserList methods (add, append, extend) to get no duplicates. For some reason, I still get `alpha` twice. I even get an empty list if I just try to print the `original_list` Here's the code I wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding: utf-8

from collections import UserList

class Ulist(UserList):
    def __init__(self, info = []):
        UserList.__init__(self)
        self.info = info

    def __add__(self, something_new):
        for i in something_new:
            if i in self:
                print('%r This is already in the list.' % (i))
            else:
                return UserList.__add__(self, something_new)

    def append(self, something_new):
        if something_new in self:
            print('%r This is already in the list.' % (i))
        else:
            return UserList.append(self, something_new)

    def extend(self, something_new):
        for i in something_new:
            if i in self:
                print('%r This is already in the list.' % (i))
            else:
                return UserList.extend(self, something_new)


# let's test how it works

original_list = Ulist(['alpha'])

original_list.__add__([444])
original_list.append('alpha')
original_list.append('I_dont_exist_yet')
original_list.append(0)
original_list.extend([98, 98, 234,'alpha','beta','I_am_totally_new',33])


print(original_list)
```

Disclaimer: I'm aware people have asked a similar question regarding UserList and method overloading. I analysed these questions but still couldn't figure out why my code doesn't work. Also, I'm new to Python.

Comment: Inside your `extend` function, you want to add each new element one by one. Don't call `UserList.extend(something_new)`, call `UserList.append(i)`.

Comment: a) why not directly subclass ``list`` itself? There's no need for UserList anymore.  b) if you don't want duplicates, use the ``set`` type.

Comment: Thanks. All the suggestions are helpful but I was trying to overload these particular methods and didn't want to use anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
from collections import UserList

class Ulist(UserList):
    def __init__(self, info = []):
        UserList.__init__(self)
        self.info = info

    def add_iterable(self, iterable):
        for i in iterable:
            if i in self:
                print('%r This is already in the list.' % (i))
            else:
                UserList.append(self, i)
        return self

    def __add__(self, something_new):
        if hasattr(something_new, '__iter__'):
            return self.add_iterable(something_new)
        else:
            return UserList.append(self, something_new)

    def append(self, something_new):
        if something_new in self:
            print('%r This is already in the list.' % (i))
        else:
            return UserList.append(self, something_new)

    def extend(self, something_new):        
        return self.add_iterable(something_new)
```

Test output:

> 98 This is already in the list.
>
> 'alpha' This is already in the list.
>
> [444, 'alpha', 'I_dont_exist_yet', 0, 98, 234, 'beta', 'I_am_totally_new', 33]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is absolutely perfect. Exactly what I meant. (Due to my rep < 15, I can't officially upvote you.)

Comment: Great. No worries. I believe you can at least accept an answer regardless of your rep

Answer (score 4):

This is only tangentially an answer, but I'd strongly recommend trying to implement similar operations in terms of each other. For example, `__add__` is really just construction followed by an `extend` operation. And `extend` is really just repeated `append`s. If performance is not absolutely critical (and when you're implementing your own `UserList`, you've already given up on performance, by and large), it's much easier to have one known good implementation and implement other operations in terms of that known good operation.

So, for example, `__add__` can be implemented as:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    ret = self.__class__(self)  # Alt: self.copy()
    ret.extend(other)
    return ret
```

So now as long as your constructor and `extend` method are correct, `__add__` is correct automatically.

Then you implement `extend` in terms of `append`:

```
def extend(self, other):
    for x in other:
        self.append(x)
```

and now, if `append` is correct, then so are `extend` and `__add__`. Now, all you need to do is get `append` correct (and you can test it in isolation until you're sure it's correct).

As it happens, your `append` is already correct (assuming `print` is a reasonable way of reporting errors, it usually isn't). So with this `__add__` and `extend`, and a working initializer method, you'd have working code.

Your existing code would not actually behave correctly regardless though. Your initializer is wrong; you set `self.info` to the input iterable but `self.info` is never used by `collections.UserList` (it uses the `data` attribute). If you want to make a safe initializer, do something like:

```
def __init__(self, info=()):  # Never use mutable default arguments
    UserList.__init__(self)
    self.extend(info)  # Reuse known good code
```

Again, this reuses known good code; if `extend` works (which in turn depends on `append`), then this initializer is good. If you want it optimized for the copy scenario, you can save duplicate checking work by using class internals:

```
def __init__(self, info=()):
    UserList.__init__(self)
    if isinstance(info, Ulist):
        # Already deduped, copy without duplicate checking
        self.data[:] = info.data
    else:
        self.extend(info)
```

The main point of this answer is: Build up from pieces, and [don't repeat yourself (mnemonic: DRY)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). Don't try to implement each method from scratch when they're all variations on one another. Identify a single "common denominator" functionality, and build on top of that, so any given method either does a single simple thing, or is implemented in terms of another method in a way that minimizes custom code.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation. Will definitely keep that in mind!